# Why there are countably many families of rational cuves on a projective variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ ba a projective variety, and $\mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ be a rational curve.

Why it is claimed that there are countably many families of rational curves on $X$ (certainly, one just need to show there are countably many families of rational curves of fixed degree with certain very ample line bundle of $X$)?

First of all, what does "family" mean in this setting.

Comment: In *which* setting are you working? enumerative geometry, e.g. counting curves on subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$? or...?

Comment: @Brenin This is the statement I read from book "Higher-dimensional algebraic geometry" by Debarre, so I guess the setting is birational geometry

Comment: Can you please provide the complete statement that you read on the book? I do not have access to the book, sorry.

Comment: One place to find more details on this is Kollár's book _Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties_, in particular Chapter II. Briefly, there is a scheme $\mathrm{RatCurves}(X)$ parametrising rational curves on $X$, which is a countable union of quasi-projective subschemes $\mathrm{RatCurves}_d(X)$ (parametrising rational curves of degree $d$), and hence has countable many components altogether. In the statement you read, I think "family" should be interpreted as meaning a component of this scheme.